# Druid `Latest` Performance implications

Tags: aggregation, latency, druid

Druid supports **Latest** aggregation in newer releases. For example, following table stores user coordinates on different time stamps. I want to know how is latest user coordinate fetched via this query on this table.

[image: user_coordinates]

```
SELECT LATEST(latitude,16), LATEST(longitude,16), user_id FROM locations
GROUP BY user_id
```

My current understanding is that since druid partitions data on time, it starts with latest partition to check if user has any coordinate update in that partition. If not found in latest partition it would go on to find in next partitions. This way if user is not present in entire database it would have to scan entire dataset before returning null value. Won't this cause query performance to be really slow?

Answer (score 0):

Queries to Druid are normally time bound with a filter on the __time field. So without the __time filter, you are correct in that it will scan the whole table.

For this use case, other implementations have opted to add periodic markers to the stream. These are data rows injected into the stream with the last known value, (location in your case) for those entities (user_id in your case) which have not reported a value within the last marker period. The period with which you do this depends on how narrow you want to make the query __time window. If you only want to query a day's worth of data to get the latest, you'd probably want to do this twice a day.